# Cheeger constant of tensor product of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, tensor-products, spectral-graph-theory

Suppose we have a simple graph G. Now if we tensor many graph G together (N graphs in total, if you need a number), a graph of much complexity is newly made. But what is the cheeger constant of our new graph? And how is it related to the original G?

Comment: The Cheeger constant of the tensor product can be zero even when the original graph has strictly positive Cheeger constant. This is because the tensor product of $G$ with itself will not be connected if $G$ is bipartite. So the simplest example is $G=K_{1,1}$, which is has Cheeger constant exactly $1$. But the tensor product is basically just two disjoint copies of $K_{1,1}$, which is not connected so the Cheeger constant is $0$. Taking higher tensors leaves it disconnected so keeps the Cheeger constant zero. So you need to assume nonbipartiteness for this to be nondegenerate.